# Why does Typescript in React not recognize the currentUser value from an exported Context with built in provider?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase-authentication

I'm attempting to have the project I'm working on update the user according with the onAuthStateChanged function from Firebase which is quite handy. So by following a tutorial I created a context with a built in provider which I wrapped my index file in:

```
import { AuthContextProvider } from './context/AuthContext';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
    <AuthContextProvider> // The wrapper
        <React.StrictMode>
            <App />
       </React.StrictMode>
    </AuthContextProvider>
);
```

This is my created context for user authentication:

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth } from '../firebase.config';

export const UserContext = createContext({});

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }: any) => {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState<any | null>({});

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsub = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
            setCurrentUser(user);
            console.log(user);
        });

        return () => {
            unsub();
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={{ currentUser }}>
            {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

And finally my actual app file where I get the error:

> TS2339: Property 'currentUser' does not exist on type '{}'.

```js
function App() {
    const styles: Styles = {
        wrapper: 'bg-purple-200 h-[100vh] w-[100vw] grid grid-cols-[minmax(100px,_250px)_1fr_minmax(150px,_250px)] grid-rows-[85%_minmax(50px,_350px)] absolute',
    };

    const { currentUser } = useContext(UserContext); //Error on this line

    const saveElem = (
        <div className={styles.wrapper}>
            <LeftBar />
            <ChatBody />
            <RightBar />
            <UserControlsContainer />
            <ChatInput />
        </div>
    );

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path='/'>
                    <Route index element={<ChatRooms />} />
                    <Route path='login' element={<LogInForm />} />
                    <Route path='signup' element={<SignUpForm />} />
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Because you are not specifying a type for your context, which you should. This type should of course include `currentUser`. Also I would reconsider the types for `currentUser` state as well.

Comment: > export const UserContext = createContext<any>({});

I got past this by having to add the <any> when creating my context. I'm still very new to Typescript so wasn't sure where or how to make it know the type, and even then bc I'm grabbing info from Firebase which has a lot of strings and stuff not sure what the best type for that would be or how to figure it out.

Thank you for your input.